# No way to stop wpa_supplicant when shutdown Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager, shutdown, wpa-supplicant

I'm a beginner on Linux. And I have installed Kubuntu, did the updates, but I can't shutdown cleanly (I have to shut down manually).

When I shutdown Kubuntu, I get a black screen with kubuntu's logo and nothing happens (I waited during 30 minutes one time and it still didn't shuting down). When I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, I get this message:

> A stop job is running for WPA supplicant (Xmin Xsec / Ymin Ysec)

I tried some things:

1. Deleted every network registered, nothing changed.
2. Entered

   ```
   systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service
   ```

   Here is the [result screen](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/14/6/1586001135-screenshot-wpa-supplicant2.png)
3. Installed "htop" to see NetworkManager processes before and after running a command

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
   ```

   Here is the [screen before](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/14/6/1586004046-screenshot-networkmanager.png)
   Here is the [screen after](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/14/6/1586004051-screenshot-networkmanager2.png)
4. Changed timeout to force the system to shutdown in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. I changed the option `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=15s`. Nothing changed.

**Do you have any idea where these problems can come from?**
All I applicated was advice from another forum.
So don't be too technical please, I'm really novice.

Comment: What version of Kubuntu are you using? A bug report says this is a known problem with some kernels. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1724805

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04. Kernel 4.15.0-91-generic. https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/15/1/1586196978-screenshot-kubuntu.png